# Generate pfx from .cer and passphrase of the pfx

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, pfx

I lost the pfx file, but I have the .cer file and I know the password used to open the lost pfx file. How how do I generate pfx? is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have the private key to that certificate:

Convert PEM to PFX:

`openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt`

Your certificate should start with "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- " and end with "-----END CERTIFICATE----- "

Your private key should start with "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" and end with "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"

**Edit:**

If you don't have openssl installed you can also make use of online converters like this one: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html

But it's generally **not** advised to upload/share your private key with anyone!

Comment: I don't have the encrypted private key but I have password used for .pfx. How do I get privateKey.key file from the password used for .pfx?

Comment: You can't. You need the private key + the certificate to accomplish what you asked for. PFX = certifcate + private key. CER/PEM = certificate. You need to look into the files for the "BEGIN ..." parts.